# Find Numbers with eight digits starting with specific number ranges

Tags: regex

I need a regex to find all eight digit Numbers that starts wit any number in the following ranges:
20-31
40-42
50-53
60-61
71
81
91-93

How is that done?

/Therese

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a code-writing service. This is easier if you don't use regex.

Comment: @AlekDepler that's false information. Regex is not evil. It has its uses just like anything else.

Comment: `(2\d|31|4[012]|5[0123]|6[01]|71|81|9[123])\d{6}`

Comment: @ctwheels it is appropriate only for very simple parsing tasks. Another way it can lead to deadlocks on certain content

Comment: @AlekDepler but telling someone that a language feature should never be used is a little harsh. Like I said, it has its uses. You're just giving users incorrect information about regex by saying "don't ever use it".

Comment: @ctwheels then what is the reason to use regex when task solution is couple lines of code with loop?

Comment: I'm new to this. I tried to do it with ^ but couldn't get it to work @L3viathan I see how your solution is smarter, defining digits with \d

Comment: @AlekDepler If writing the code is not appropriate for the task and a quick regex is needed (for one). I know I've used regex to parse hundreds of thousands of lines of data to pull specific information when we were in a great rush to get results. Writing a program would have taken substantially longer. It also depends on the task at hand. If performance is an issue (especially when you're talking nested loops) it may be possible to replace the whole task with a single (probably complex) regex pattern. To completely disregard a language altogether because you deem it *evil* seems illogical

Comment: @AlekDepler there may also be instances where you're looking for a particular pattern in a string (the majority of use cases for regex). These cannot be easily replicated with string functions. For example, write me a program that will find every occurrence of `a` followed by any letter then by `d` in a string. Much easier to do this in  regex.

Comment: @Therese Maybe surround it with `\b` to not match 8-long digit runs within longer numbers: https://regex101.com/r/j4B2ot/1

Comment: Regex is great for dull search-and-replace tasks, it's not "evil". Of course, it can easily be used wrong, but just because something is easy to misuse doesn't make it evil. Similar to how the `rm` command in linux isn't "evil", just because you can more or less delete your filesystem if you type it with the right (wrong?) parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using word boundaries (as otherwise e.g. the 20 in 2018 gets matched) with the regex `\b(2\d|31|4[012]|5[0-3]|6[01]|[78]1|9[1-3])\d{6}\b`.

Here is a live example in Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/99DToMd0LG.

Comment: You can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`, `[0123]` with `[0-3]`, and `71|81` with `[78]1` to make it shorter (the last one makes it perform better).

Comment: Thank you for your input -- I have updated my answer. :)

Comment: Also, OP is looking for numbers that begin with these two digits with another 6 digits following it: `\b(?:(?:2\d|31|4[012]|5[0-3]|6[01]|[78]1|9[123])\d{6})\b`

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches digits in range `20-31`... meaning from `20000000` to `30999999`.

**Regex**: `\b(?:2\d|30|4[01]|5[012]|60|71|81|9[12])\d{6}\b`

**Details**:

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`), `[0-2]` is equal to `[012]`
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `|` Or

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJaeSu/1)

Comment: `31` not `30`, it's missing `42`, `61` (not `60`), `93`

Comment: @ctwheels range 30-31, (42,61,93) are upper limits, range 60-61

Comment: Sorry you're right about `60`, but the rest are all missing. The OP mentions `any number in the following ranges` which implies it includes the upper limits (this can be proven with the indication of `71` being explicit and `60-61` implying both numbers should be included.

Comment: @ctwheels they are upper limits. 20-31 means from 20000000 - 30999999.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. You should ask the OP to elaborate on this. We're both making different assumptions without basis.

Comment: @ctwheels Then OP should change regex to its needs.

Comment: As much as I'd agree the OP should change the regex to their needs, you really should ask for clarification if there's uncertainty as you shouldn't be answering the question without enough information.